# Android:Scrollbar for running graph

Tags: android, graph, custom-controls, scrollbar, dynamic-data

I've a custom view which draws a running graph - some magnitude versus time. Now I want to implement a custom scroll bar for this so that I can view past data which are offscreen. The data is available to me. I just need the %offset selection by the user.

Any help/suggestions on implementation would be v helpful.

Code Snippet from my Custom view's onDraw method

public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

```
    int totalpts = data.size();
    scale = getWidth() / (float) maxpoints;
    List<Data> display = new ArrayList<Data>();
    int initial = 1;
    if (totalpts > maxpoints) {
        initial = totalpts - maxpoints;

            display = data.subList(initial, data.size() - 1);

    } else {

            display = data;

    }


    int size = display.size();
    Data start = null;
    float x1 = 0, x2 = 0, x = 0;

    if (size > 1) {
        x1 = getWidth();
        start = display.get(display.size() - 1);
        for (int i = display.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            Data stop = display.get(i);
            x = x1;
            x1 -= (stop.x * scale / 1000);

            canvas.drawLine(x, start.Y, x1, stop.Y, paint1);

            start = stop;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your custom control inside a [HorizonatalScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html) (assuming you want it to scroll horizontally), use [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) otherwise), setting the width of your control to "WRAP_CONTENT", and the HoizontalScrollView to "FILL_PARENT". Without seeing the code for your custom view, it's difficult to know whether you might need to  do some tinkering with the width calculation to get this working.

Comment: Thanks Mark. But I don't think I can add HorizontalScrollView since at any point of time my draw method draws only points that can fit within its assigned width. I've added the required code snippet to my question. Anything else I can do? or any other way to implement draw?

Comment: Sorry, I really don't understand what you're trying to do, in that case.